# Android - Action on progress dialog exit

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I'm trying to write a pretty basic app for my phone, just to get myself back into the swing of programming. I've got the framework and the basics of what I want to do, I just need help on a small section that's killing me.

On my app, I have a button. When that button is pressed I want the app to change a piece of text to "Deciding...", pop up an indeterminate progress bar for a second or two then exit, then print the result of another activity, but only after the dialog has exited. I'm using a thread at the moment, but I can't get it to function correctly.

Does anyone have any idea how to get it to work the way I want it to?

Here's my Activity file source:

```
package com.bassios.decisionengine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DecisionEngineActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public String decision;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

public void decide(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Decision1);
    tv.setText("Deciding...");
    int a = generate();
    decision = decision(a);
    runDialog(1);
//        alterText();
}

public void alterText() {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Decision1);
    tv.setText(decision);
}

private void runDialog(final int seconds) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Deciding...");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static int generate() {
    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    return a;
}

public static String decision(int a) {
    String decision = null;
    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            decision = "Yes";
            break;
        case 2:
            decision = "No";
            break;
        case 3:
            decision = "Yes";
            break;
        case 4:
            decision = "No";
            break;
        case 5:
            decision = "Yes";
            break;
        case 6:
            decision = "No";
            break;
        case 7:
            decision = "Yes";
            break;
        case 8:
            decision = "No";
            break;
        case 9:
            decision = "Yes";
            break;
        case 10:
            decision = "No";
            break;
    }
    return decision;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `AsyncTask` instead of `Thread`, You cannot change the state of UI from another `Thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTask.

An example:

http://javatech.org/2011/02/discovering-android-opening-a-progress-dialog-with-asynctask/

**Update:**

First of all, you must declare the class like this:

```
private class DecideTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{
...
}
```

I don't know how `showDialog` and `removeDialog` works, but I would do it like this instead:

Show dialog (in `onPreExecute`):

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...",
                "Deciding...", true);
```

Remove/dismiss dialog (in `onPostExecute`):

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Declaring each of the three methods:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)

protected void onPreExecute()

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
```

That should do it.

Comment: I'm trying to use that example, but when I paste it in to alter it to fit, I get this:


com.bassios.decisionengine.DecisionEngineActivity.decideTask is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(java.lang.Object...) in android.os.AsyncTask

Comment: I've put it on PasteBin 'cause it's too long to fit in the comments here: http://pastebin.com/2BpZssjV

Comment: What happens if you don't uncomment the override above the doInBackground method?

Comment: Either way I still get the same error. Uncommenting the @Override gives me "Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I was out yesterday. I've got the majority of it working now, but the dialog box isn't working. I'm getting a huge error message on the progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(...); line now.

I've uploaded the error message as a screenshot for you, it's far too large to type out. http://i42.tinypic.com/2evxjj7.jpg

EDIT: I should probably mention that I'm developing in NetBeans because Eclipse wouldn't work (it couldn't find my jvm). I don't know if that makes any difference or not though.

Comment: Instead of `this`, try using `DecisionEngineActivity.this`.

Comment: That's sorted it! Thanks so much! I should really have known to do that myself. I'll remember that in future should I get a similar error message. Thanks so much for your help.